# Função que retorna mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

O meu cenário é seguinte: eu tenho uma função chamada buscaUsuario()

```
function buscaUsuario($conexao)
{

$retornar = array();
$query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT user_name FROM usuarios");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $retornar[] = $result;
}

return $retornar;

}
```

Onde também tenho um arquivo chamado procura-usuario.php e lá tem o seguinte trecho de código:

```
                        <?php 

                        $all = buscaUsuario($conexao);
                        $ab = sizeof($all);
                        $i = 0;
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $ab; $i++)
                        {
                         ?>
                         <tr>
                            <td><?=implode($all[$i])?></td>
                         </tr> <?php
                         }
                         ?>
```

Eu estou retornando a query em um array pra ser exibida numa tabela. Anteriormente tentei fazer de uma forma mais sucinta (pelo menos pra mim) mas entrava num loop infinito e crashava o navegador. E essa outra forma era a seguinte: na função buscaUsuario() eu criava uma variável que recebia mysqli_fetch_array() e retornava essa variável. Então, em procura-usuario.php eu chamava essa função e jogava dentro de um while para que a tabela fosse populada até não ter mais nenhuma linha dentro do array... E isso (como eu disse ali em cima) fazia o navegador crashar, aí resolvi fazer dessa forma que lhes mostrei. Porém, se eu adiciono mais um campo no select e mando imprimir dentro desse for, a as células de cada linha na tabela não são populadas, apenas a primeira linha, ficando assim: usuarioNomeCompletoIdadeSexo

Eu queria entender o que estou fazendo de errado e qual seria a melhor forma de fazer o que estou tentando fazer... Obrigado folks!

Comment: Um foreach não resolve? `$all = buscaUsuario($conexao); foreach($all as $item){ echo $item['user_name'] .'<br>';}`

Comment: Já havia tentado, mas ele dá o seguinte erro: Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_name'

Comment: Então o nome da coluna está errado, só isso. Qual é o nome correto da coluna? na dúvida troque o `echo $item ...` por `print_r($item)` dentro do foreach.

Comment: Nope, está correto. user_name

Comment: Coloca o resultado do `print_r()` no comentário que já resolvemos haha

Comment: O resultado é: "admin", do qual é um dos user_name cadastrados... Creio que mostrou admin primeiro por estar sendo ordenado alfabeticamente

Comment: Não é só admin tem mais coisas, o retorno deve ser algo mais ou menos assim `Array ( [chave] => valor )`

Comment: Pior que não brother, retorna apenas "admin" :\
Lá no outro arquivo, mude mysqli_fetch_assoc para mysqli_fetch_array e o print_R retornou dois admin

Comment: Aah, dentro do foreach, deixe apenas `echo $item .'<br>';`

Comment: Novamente apareceu somente "admin"

Comment: Então agora está certo é só formatar na tabela html, ou faltou alguma coisa?

Comment: Na verdade não, pois tenho 5 user_name no meu banco de dados e está sendo exibido um registro apenas. E também já está formatado na tabela html D:

Answer (score 1):

Cara, você pode tentar fazer da seguinte forma:

```
function buscaUsuario($conexao)
{

$query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT user_name FROM usuarios");

return mysqli_fetch_array($query)

}
```

E na outra:

```
<?php 

$all = buscaUsuario($conexao);
while($all)
{
?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $all["user_name"]; ?></td>
   </tr> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Assim fica muito mais prático e você economiza mais da metade das linhas..

Comment: Isso aí da um loop infinito, vc sempre retorna a primeira linha da consulta, o while nunca será false.

Comment: É dá um loop infinito. Era assim que eu havia feito anteriormente e crashou diversas vezes o navegador...

Comment: Editei o código, pega a função de novo e testa pra ver

Answer (score 0):

Consegui listar usando desta forma:

```
function jQueryArray($sql) {
    $tbl = array();
    $linkConexao = conectaBD();
    $rs = mysqli_query($linkConexao, $sql);

    $i = 0;

    while ($tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){ $i++;

        $tblReturn[$i] = $tbl;

    }


    desconectaBD($linkConexao);
    return $tblReturn;
}

// Lista na view
$tbl = jQueryArray($sql);   

<table  class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped posts">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Motivo</td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>                
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php  foreach ($tbl as $value){   ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value['id_motivo'];  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['descricao'];  ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <?php  } ?>

    </table>
```